# Add facebook like button in wordpress e-commerce site

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I'm building wordpress e-commerce site (using wp e-commerce plugin), so i added Facebook Open Graph Protocol, so now my site is connected to facebook and i can put facebook like button for the entire web site or for pages or for posts,but i want to add like button for all of the products of my sites, i tried many plugins but none of them works for me. I read on some forums that i should add some code to single-product.php, but there are 3 files with that name.
If anybody knows how this works, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: i didn't know until now that I can accept answers (I'm relatively new in Stackoverflow).

Comment: "Please help me..." doesn't get you too much sympathy around here. Do some homework first: start by looking at the differences in those three files. Are they page templates? Are they all wp-e-commerce files? Which ones are in play for single product display? What did the forums say? What code did they offer? Did you try it?

Comment: hahaha, good thing the community is so helpful

Comment: single-priduct.php is inside wp e-commerce/themes/Default,iShop and marketplace and is the same. The code is very simple, it is used for adding the like button which is working on the posts and pages, but not for the products.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed tutorial on how to integrate the Facebook Like Button with Wordpress on my blog here:

http://abecoffman.com/2011/advanced-wordpress-like-button-integration/

If you follow the steps you should be able to add the XFBML tags anywhere in your theme.